# Как понимать "обман военкомата" — военкомат обманут или обманывает?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, грамматика, смысл

В общем. Сёрфил по ютубу, увидел в рекомендациях видео “Обман военкомата”. Я сразу подумал, что автор сейчас будет рассказывать способы обмана военкомата. Но оказалось видео о том, что военкомат обманул его.

Теперь я не могу понять. “Обман военкомата” - это когда ты пытаешься обмануть военкомат или военкомат тебя? Как мне кажется, фраза звучит в обе стороны.

> **Обман военкомата** *(кого или что будем обманывать?)*
>   **Обман военкомата** *(кого? чей обман? от кого обман?)*

Будет ли правильным моя мысль, что если военкомат обманывает тебя, то правильно будет сказать **Обман от военкомата**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обман от** прям слух режет. Если вы хотите убрать двусмысленность, то можно сказать **обман со стороны военкомата**.

Comment: ну да, точно, почему я сразу не догадался